# Python escape space character in filenames when listing directories

Tags: bash, python-3.x, shell

Note: I am new to python.

I am using python3.5 with the following code to recursively perform actions on files of directories.  This is a simplified version which shows the problem I have:

```
import os

rootdir="/home/some_path"

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        print(subdir + '/' + file)
```

An example output is the following which is wrong because it doesn't escape the space characters and causes file to not be found:

```
/home/spaces file3
/home/spaces file1
/home/.file1
/home/spaces file2
/home/-file3
```

Ideally, what I want is:

```
/home/spaces\ file3
```

so that the path I create is correct and the file is successfully found.  How can I do it? What is the slickest way?

Note that what I actually want, is to not print in screen, but to run a bash function like `du` in the following way:

```
import subcall
import os

rootdir="/home/some_path"

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        sp.call("du -B1 " + subdir + '/' + file, shell=True)
```

Comment: Maybe `repr()`?

Comment: Don't mangle the file names in Python; fix the script reading them to handle spaces correctly.

Comment: Classic [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). You still haven't shown us what `sp` is, for example. And backslashes are really **not necessary** if you pass arguments normally, like with `subprocess.check_call`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want is for Python to print strings which you can use in shell programs to reliably loop over paths. Since paths in *nix can contain literally every byte except NUL (`\0`) the generally accepted solution for doing this is to **use NUL as the filename terminator:**

```
sys.stdout.write("{}{}".format(os.path.join(subdir, file), '\0'))
```

You can then use the result with commands that can readNUL-terminated items, such as most of the GNU tools.

Comment: This is almost always the best approach. BTW, you can also read a null-delimited file list in a pure-bash loop with `while IFS= read -d "" -r file; do ... done <filelist.txt` (and then wrap all occurrences of `"$file"` in double-quotes, like I just did). See [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) for more info.

Comment: In the solution, the ending right bracket is missing

Comment: Also, It doesn't look to work because the result now is:
`/home/spaces file146
/home/.file140
/home/.file240`

Comment: No ` \ ` where added and in addition, instead of `.file1` I now have `.file140` etc